# API Managment unable to cast response body as string

Tags: azure-api-management

In Azure API Management, when the response going back to the client is a 500, I wish to check the body of the response to see if it matches "Some text".  I need to do this so that I may change the body of the response to contain some more helpful text in this particular scenario.

The following `<outbound>` section of my policy is accepted by the API Management console, but when I test and get a 500, API Management generates an error -

> Expression evaluation failed. Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.MessageBody' to type 'System.String'.

I'm guessing this is my fault, but does anybody know how I can amend the ploicy so that it does not generate an error?  To clarify, the error is being generated by this line - `((string)(object)context.Response.Body == "Some text")`.

```
<outbound>
    <choose>
        <when condition="@((context.Response.StatusCode == 500) && ((string)(object)context.Response.Body == "Some text"))">
            <set-status code="500" reason="Internal Server Error" />
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>
                {
                    "statusCode": "500",
                    "Message": "Some different, more helpful text."
                }
            </set-body>
        </when>
    </choose>
</outbound>
```

---

## Update

I've discovered that `context.Response.Body` is of type `IMessageBody`.  There seems to be woefully little documentation around this type, and the only reference I can find comes under `<set-body>` in the [Transformation Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBody) API management documentation.

The troube is, the example that MS havd documented produces an exception when I try and save my policy -

```
<set-body>
@{
    JObject inBody = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>();
    if (inBody.attribute == <tag>) {
        inBody[0] = 'm';
    }
    return inBody.ToString();
}
</set-body>
```

> Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: The original sample contains reading body as string, thus indexer works since string type supports changing individual letters. Where as JObject does not have writeable indexer with int index.

Comment: When I try [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#example-accessing-the-body-as-a-jobject-note-that-since-we-are-not-reserving-the-original-request-body-accessing-it-later-in-the-pipeline-will-result-in-an-exception) I get: `"message": "Expression evaluation failed.",
            "expression": "\n                    var response = context.Request.Body.As<String>();\n                    return response.ToString();\n                ",
            "details": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
        }`  why!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try context.Request.Body.As<string>(). Method As currently supports following types as generic argument value:

- byte[]
- string
- JToken
- JObject
- JArray
- XNode
- XElement
- XDocument

Mind that if you try to call .As<JObject> over response that does not contain valid JSON you would get an exception, same applies to other types as well.