# Unable to convert Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.PipelineResponse type to string type

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-policy, apim

I have APIM policy where I am using following policy

```
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(!(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("Value").Contains("admin")))">
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="403" reason="Forbidden" />
            </return-response>
        </when>
    </choose>
```

When policy parsing at run it throw error

"details": "Unable to convert context variable `Value` of type `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.PipelineResponse` to the type of `System.String`.\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.Context.ExpressionSyntaxExtensions.GetValueOrDefault[T](IReadOnlyDictionary`2 dictionary, String key, T defaultValue)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [API Managment unable to cast response body as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505746/api-managment-unable-to-cast-response-body-as-string)

Comment: [APIM Policy - Unable to cast object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68480191/apim-policy-unable-to-cast-object)

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution for this post.
I  updated policy from following syntax

```
       <choose>
        <when condition="@(!((IResponse)context.Variables["Value"]).Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true).ToString().Contains("admin"))">
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="403" reason="Forbidden" />
            </return-response>
        </when>
       </choose>
```